Prevent webpack from minifying component name
I am using component.name to get components name and pass it to a function that checks whether the component is available for current user. During build webpack minifies component names so my checks stop working.
I tried adding webpack-react-component-name
to the project with the help of react-app-rewired but it doesn't seem to do what I need. How can I preserve components names on build?
const OrderList = () => {
  const isDesktop = useIsDesktop();
  const { getIsComponentEnabled } = useIsComponentEnabled();
  const isComponentEnabled = getIsComponentEnabled(OrderList.name);

  if (!isComponentEnabled) return <Navigate to="/overview" replace={true} />;

  return (
    <PageWrapper>
      <Box display="flex" justifyContent="space-between" alignItems="center">
        <PageHeading sx={{ paddingY: 5 }}>ORDERS</PageHeading>
        <OrderListOIButtons />
      </Box>
      <PageTypeProvider PageType="OrderList">
        <MainContentGridContainer>
          <LeftGrid>
            {isDesktop ? (
              <>
                <PageFilters />
                <ContentTable />
              </>
            ) : (
              <PageCard />
            )}
          </LeftGrid>
          {isDesktop && (
            <RightGrid>
              <ItemDetails />
            </RightGrid>
          )}
        </MainContentGridContainer>
      </PageTypeProvider>
    </PageWrapper>
  );
};

export default OrderList;

// config-overrides.js
const WebpackReactComponentNamePlugin = require("webpack-react-component-name");
    
    module.exports = function override(config) {
      config.plugins[5].options = {
        ...config.plugins[5].options,
        filename: "react/static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].css",
        chunkFilename: "react/static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.css",
      };
      config.output = {
        ...config.output, // copy all settings
        filename: "react/static/js/[name].js",
        chunkFilename: "react/static/js/[name].chunk.js",
      };
      config.plugins.push(new WebpackReactComponentNamePlugin());
    
      return config;
    };


If it's already hardcoded, why not just call it like getIsComponentEnabled('OrderList'); and replace the string for different components? Now it's the same thing but with an extra step.

To me, it seemed that it would help avoid typos because I can rename function name in VSCode with F2 and replace all of the mentions of the variable down the line.

Check this answer for disabling name mangling from webpack. How to disable in Webpack to rename of function names? TypeScript, Javascript. However I'm not sure if relying on compile-level function names for authentication is a good approach, though.
